# Load data in directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I have a directive in Angular which gets updated from an array in the `$scope` and populates its data through an `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">
    ...
    <div>{{value.personid}}</div>
    ...
</div>
```

As you see in the array I have a `personid` and what I want to do is get the name for the respective person from the api working behind Angular. I'm not sure how to approach this. I do have a couple of ideas:

1. Create a filter, pass the `personid` as input and make an AJAX call to the api to get the name. That though would be a lot of calls to the server and I'm not really sure if filters should be used in this way.
2. When I create the array in the controller, iterate it there and make the calls that are needed before assigning the values to the `$scope`, then just display them in the view.

Both solutions will be quite intensive so which one is better or even yet, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most easy is to just pass full decorated objects to the directive. Make sure `$scope.items` looks like this (example):

```
[
    {
        id: 12,
        name: 'John'
    },
    {
        id: 83,
        name: 'Mary'
    },
    {
        id: 92,
        name: 'Jane'
    },
]
```

And now you can loop over the user objects like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in items">
    ...
    <div>{{ user.name }} has id {{ user.id }}</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Which will print out

```
John has id 12
Mary has id 83
Jane has id 92
```

Easy does it!

**EDIT** reading your question again; do I understand you *only* have the ids available in your controller? In that case you only have two options: fire a search query passing *all* the ids, and let the server return you the full user objects. This will only cost you a single xhr call. Otherwise, well, yeah, you do need to fire a call for each user.... Which I would avoid at all costs.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I only have the ids, not the names and I have to do some additional work to get the names. Collecting all the ids and making only one additional call to the server though seems like a very nice idea!

Answer (score 1):

You can try a service via filter:

```
app.service('getperson', function() {
    this.getperson= function (x) {
          person = <lookup logic>
        return person;
    }
});
app.filter('personinfo',['getperson', function(getperson) {
    return function(x) {
        return getperson.myFunc(x);
    };
}]);
```

Then you can insert into your statement:

```
<div>{{value.personid | personinfo}}</div>
```

see if that works for you

WARNING.  this calls back to the db for every record. Otherwise, add to the initial scope all the info you need.